# Needs["Mongolink`"] is failing when we run from Mathematica online (version 12.00

Tags: mongodb

When we write a *Mathematica* function to access Mongodb database at the backend, the very basic [`Needs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html) call to Mongolink is failing when it is called in the ONLINE version.

When the code is running outside the online version and in a local desktop version, the `` Needs["Mongodb`"] `` is working fine.

The error message that comes in when trying to run the Needs call in the online version is as follows:

Comment: The error message is missing from your post. In any case, this is a case where we are less likely to be able to help you than the official Wolfram support team. Please get in contact with them about this issue.

Comment: Can you paste your code... what mongo server are you connecting to?